# Accessing Nested structure variable

Tags: c, arrays, struct, nested, structure

When I tried to compile the following program, it gives me no output on screen:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
struct d1
{
char arr [10];
int num;
};

struct d2
{
struct d1 name;
int age;
}p1;

p1.name={("JANE",8)};
printf ("%s",&p1.name.arr[0]);
}
```

I think problem is due to line `p1.name={("JANE",8)};`
But I think I have written everything right. By writing this line I tried to assign value to a member,`"name"` of variable `p1` having structure type `d2`. And as `name` is itself a structure of type `d1` having two members, so I assigned two values `JANE` and `8` to `arr [10]` and `num` members of `name` respectively.

I even tried with

`p1.name={{"JANE",8}}; //For this it gives error`

`p1.name={("JANE",8),20}; //For this it compiles but no output`

`p1.name={{"JANE",8},20}; //again error`

That `20` is value of `p1's` member  `"age"`. While trying to print value `p1.name.age` it gives `0` instead of`20`.

**What's wrong? Is there any syntax error or a conceptual error?**

Comment: You need typecast, because compiler does not know, what literal `{"JANE",8}` is. Use `p1.name=(struct d1){"JANE",8};`

Comment: @RomanHocke It is not typecasting. It is the compound literal

Comment: @Avi - we should not answer it. You even did not bother to format the code

Answer (score 3):

1. The form you use is only allowed if you initilize the structure. You need to use compound literals.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{

    struct d1
    {
        char arr [10];
        int num;
    };

    struct d2
    {
        struct d1 name;
        int age;
    }p1;

    p1.name=(struct d1){"JANE",8};
    printf ("%s",p1.name.arr);
}
```

Comment: The printf() is okay, he has `&...[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

if is is an initialization do directly :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  struct d1
  {
    char arr [10];
    int num;
  };

  struct d2
  {
    struct d1 name;
    int age;
  }p1 = {{"JANE",8}, 20};

  printf ("%s",&p1.name.arr[0]);
}
```

`p1.name.num` is 8 and `p1.age` is 20

note `&p1.name.arr[0]` can be `p1.name.arr`